# How to automatically authenticate against the kubernetes cluster after creating it with terraform in Azure?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

## Question:

I try to create a kubernetes cluster, namespace and secrets via terraform. 
The cluster is created, but the resources building upon the cluster fail to be created.

## Background information

### Error message:

This is the error message thrown by terraform after creation of the kubernetes cluster, when the namespace is to be created:

```
azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool.mypool: Creation complete after 6m4s [id=/subscriptions/aaabcde1-abcd-abcd-abcd-aaaaaaabdce/resourcegroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/my-aks/agentPools/win]        
Error: Post https://my-aks-abcde123.hcp.australiaeast.azmk8s.io:443/api/v1/namespaces: dial tcp: lookup my-aks-abcde123.hcp.australiaeast.azmk8s.io on 10.128.10.5:53: no such host

  on mytf.tf line 114, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "my":
 114: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "my" {
```

### Manual workaround:

I can resolve this by manually authenticating against the kubernetes cluster via the command line and applying the outstanding terraform changes via another `terraform apply`:

```
az aks get-credentials -g myrg -n my-aks --overwrite-existing
```

### Automated workaround attempt:

My attempt to automate this authentication step failed. I have tried with a local exec provisioner inside the definition of the kubernetes cluster, without success:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "myCluster" {
  name                = "my-aks"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "my-aks"
  network_profile {
    network_plugin      = "azure"
  }

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_B2s"
  }
  service_principal {
    client_id     = azuread_service_principal.tfapp.application_id
    client_secret = azuread_service_principal_password.tfapp.value
  }
  tags = {
    Environment = "demo"
  }
  windows_profile {
    admin_username = "myself"
    admin_password = random_string.password.result
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command="az aks get-credentials -g myrg -n my-aks --overwrite-existing"
  }
}
```

This is an example of a resource that fails to be created:

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "my" {
  metadata {
    name = "my-namespace"
  }
}
```

Is there a way to fully automate the creation of my resources, including those that are based on the kubernetes cluster, without manual authentication?

Comment: Do you create all the things with only one Terraform file?

Comment: Yes, I do... how could splitting it up solve it? Do you have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your requirements, I think you can separate the creation of the AKS cluster from the creation of the resources in the AKS cluster.

In the creation of the AKS cluster, you just need to put the provisioner `local-exec` in the `null_resource` like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command="az aks get-credentials -g ${azurerm_resource_group.rg.name} -n my-aks --overwrite-existing"
  }
}
```

When the AKS cluster creation is finished. Then you go to create your namespace through the Terraform again.

In this way, you do not need to manually authenticate. Just execute the Terraform code.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually got this to work, without any requiredment to use AZ LOGIN, or AZ AKS GET-CREDENTIALS null_resource or local-exec provisioners as suggested above etc.

Instead used a data block in main.tf to obtain the AKS Cluster (output from AKS module), and use the KUBE ADMIN CONFIG from the DATA as credentials for the Kubernetes Provider block. See below:

```
  data "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = local.aks_cluster_name
  resource_group_name = module.infra_resource_group.rg.name

  depends_on = [
    module.aks.aks_cluster
  ]
}

  provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config.0.host
  client_certificate     = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_admin_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}
```

NOTE: Found that using KUBE_CONFIG in the Kubernetes Provider block did not work. It needed higher permissions, hence why used the KUBE_ADMIN_CONFIG attribute instead

Using:

- Terraform v0.15.0
- AzureRM Provider 2.60.0
- Kubernetes Provider 2.2.0

Answer (score 0):

In [the documentation for Terraform AKS resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html) there is an example of creating an authenticated Kubernetes provider:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.host}"
  username               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.username}"
  password               = "${azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.password}"
  client_certificate     = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.client_certificate)}"
  client_key             = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.main.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
}
```

Then you can create Kubernetes [namespace](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/namespace.html) or [secret](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/r/secret.html) with Terraform.