# Namespace creation failing in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks

We are trying to create `namespaces` through `terraform` in our AKS cluster. However, it keeps failing with errors. Using `Service Principal` for `az login`

configuration -

```
resource "null_resource" "aks_login" {
  triggers = {
    always_run = "${timestamp()}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az aks get-credentials -g rg-my-cluster -n my-cluster --admin --overwrite-existing"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test0" {
  metadata {
    name = "ns-test0"
  }
  depends_on = [null_resource.aks_login]
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "test1" {
  for_each = toset( var.testVal )
  metadata {
    labels = {
      istio-injection = "enabled"
    }
    name = "ns-test1-${each.key}"
  }
  depends_on = [null_resource.aks_login]
}
```

The error is as:

```
module.namespaces.null_resource.aks_login (local-exec): Executing: ["/bin/sh" "-c" "az aks get-credentials -g rg-my-cluster -n my-cluster --admin --overwrite-existing"]
module.namespaces.null_resource.aks_login (local-exec): Merged "my-cluster-admin" as current context in /home/hpad/.kube/config
module.namespaces.null_resource.aks_login: Creation complete after 1s [id=1979085082878134694]
module.namespaces.kubernetes_namespace.test0: Creating...
module.namespaces.kubernetes_namespace.test1["t1"]: Creating...


Error: Post "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused

Error: Post "http://localhost/api/v1/namespaces": dial tcp [::1]:80: connect: connection refused
```

It is still considering a local k8s cluster for creation even though login to AKS is happening. Am I missing something here or it might be due to a bug in providers.

`kubernetes` provider configuration is empty currently. However, we don't have `kubeconfig` file so can't use that. Also, using `host`, `client_certificate`, `client_key` and `cluster_ca_certificate` is throwing `Unauthorized` error (because it should, access is blocked through that)

Taken some references from -

[How to always run local-exec with Terraform](https://ilhicas.com/2019/08/17/Terraform-local-exec-run-always.html)

[How to automatically authenticate against the kubernetes cluster after creating it with terraform in Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60383134/how-to-automatically-authenticate-against-the-kubernetes-cluster-after-creating)

[Create Resource Dependencies](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/dependencies)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases it's not practical to both instantiate a new service *and* make use of it with a separate provider in the same Terraform configuration, because this break's Terraform's model of creating a full plan before taking any action. The failure in this case is likely because Terraform is trying to plan the creation of `kubernetes_namespace.test0` at the same time as planning the creation of the Kubernetes cluster itself, and that isn't possible because the cluster hasn't been created yet.

The most robust way to get this done, then, is to split this Terraform configuration into two separate parts: first, a configuration that uses the `azurerm` provider to create the cluster, and then separately a configuration which has a properly-configured `provider "kubernetes"` block which refers to the cluster that the first configuration created.

Your example also shows an attempt to use a `local-exec` provisioner to acquire credentials. Again, that isn't possible because provisioners happen during the apply step rather than the plan step, and so there would be no configuration available during planning.

The typical way to use Terraform is to perform any necessary login steps separately from Terraform *before* running it, such as running `az login` and `az aks get-credentials` at your shell prompt beforehand. Then the appropriate Terraform providers should automatically detect the credentials and possibly other settings the same way as other tools for the target platform conventionally do, whether by environment variables or credentials files depending on the usual conventions for that service.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Martin!
I forgot to include info - the aks cluster is already created before still it was failing.

However, as a temporary workaround, I created a shell script and a paramterized yaml which I am using after Terraform execution completes to create namespaces.